# How to convert string (dd/MM/yyy) into date format in vb.net

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, type-conversion, datetimepicker

I already tried the following code:

```
Dim strDate as string = "25/02/2018"
Dim dateX as Date = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate)
datetimepicker1.Value = dateX
```

but I cannot get the result, the error message is "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Does anyone know how to solve this issue ?

Regards,

Comment: Where does this string come from in your real code? Is it user input? Stored in a file? Something else?

Comment: To answer the question as asked, the `Parse`, `TryParse`, `ParseExact` and `TryParseExact` methods of the `DateTime` structure can all be used to convert `Strings` to `Dates` and allow you to specify various formatting options.  It's best to avoid having to make those conversions if possible though, so the reason you have a `String` in the first place is relevant.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the string was came from datagridview value

Comment: @jmcilhinney could you please write the sample code ?

Comment: So, to get the value from the cell, did you a) access the `Value` property, which could have been any form of object, including *hopefully* a `DateTime` already, or b) call `ToString()` on it and cause yourself the problem in the first place?

Comment: Further to what @Damien_The_Unbeliever said, how does the data get into the grid in the first place?  It would be better if you were working with `DateTime` values natively, which is not hard to do.  As suggested, you might already have such values and you're the one messing them up.  If, for instance, you are querying a database and getting `DateTime` values from it into a `DataTable` and binding that to the grid, which is the most common use of a `DataGridView`, then the data is a `DateTime` already so there's no need for conversion.

Comment: **"could you please write the sample code"**. Are you suffering from some affliction that prevents you from making even the slightest attempt to do it for yourself?  I'm happy to help with stuff that people have been struggling with but I'm not here to write your code so you don't have to bother.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I used the (b) point 0 call the ToString() method.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for your advice, let me try your suggestion :)

Comment: your code is working fine for me!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim strDate as String = "25/02/2018"
Dim dateX as DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy" , Nothing)
```

That will get you: 2/25/2018 12:00:00 AM

If you want to manipulate it more, then use string methods from the date time to get certain formatting.